# SOQL - Return rows with one date column from rows with multiple date columns

Tags: mysql, split, row, soql

## Problem

I have this child table:

```
+------+------------+------------+
| Name |   Date_A   |   Date_B   | 
+------+------------+------------+
| John | 2017-08-13 | 2017-08-14 |
| Mary | 2017-08-12 | 2017-08-15 |
+------+------------+------------+
```

And I would like to get this result:

```
+------+------------+
| Name |    Date    |
+------+------------+
| Mary | 2017-08-12 |
| John | 2017-08-13 |
| John | 2017-08-14 |
| Mary | 2017-08-15 |
+------+------------+
```

---

## Research

I've been searching for a few hours now and all I can find is complicated row split with functions or solutions to merge multiple rows into one but this is the complete opposite of my problem.

I've alwready looked into solutions using UNION ALL, GROUP BY, ORDER BY, CONNECT BY and INNER JOIN but none of them fitted my needs.

I am sure that the solution is simple but I can't find the right query !

---

## Notes

The query must contain simple soql and only call the database once for it to work.

EDIT: The UNION keyword isn't supported by SOQL unfortunately :(

---

## EDIT: Solution

It seems there is no solution to this problem using SOQL but to make multiple requests and manually merge the results.

With SQL, we would only have to use UNION (as in the answers below) but this isn't supported by SOQL for now.

Comment: select name, date_a as date from table_name union select name, date_b as date from table_name;

Answer (score 2):

One option uses a `UNION`:

```
SELECT Name, Date_A AS Date
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, Date_B
FROM yourTable
```

The trick here is to stack the two date columns (with their associated names) on top of each other.

Comment: This works perfectly with classic SQL. Unfortunately, I forgot to precise it was sOql and not sql, meaning I can't use UNION... :(

Comment: Are you certain of that?  Most frameworks usually allow doing a raw query.  I'd be surprised if that were not possible.

Comment: I work with Salesforce and I'm able to execute a raw query using SOQL which, if I use UNION, throws an error saying it's not available.

Comment: I'm not seeing a solution using join here.  UNION is ideal because it allows us to create the records we want in the result set.  Maybe you could export your data and handle it outside of SOQL.

Comment: Yeah, I see. I might have to do multiple requests then. Thank's for the help !